# Gstreamer playing audio from video file with (uri)decodebin - high CPU usage

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer to convert audio from files/RTMP/RTSP streams and then analyze it.

The problem is, if my source file is video or videostream gstreamer uses a lot of CPU.

Example 1 (video) - uses 30-35% of CPU as htop says.

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri='test.mp4' ! autoaudiosink
```

Example 2 (audio from video file above converted with ffmpeg -c copy) - uses 2-4% of CPU

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri='test.mp3' ! autoaudiosink
```

How can I specify that I only need audio source from the video file?

I'm using decodebin because I don't know which files (formats) I will get from users.

Answer (score 1):

for the above examples you could use playbin a set the flags property:

```
flags               : Flags to control behaviour
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Flags "GstPlayFlags" Default: 0x00000617, "soft-colorbalance+deinterlace+soft-volume+text+audio+video"
                           (0x00000001): video            - Render the video stream
                           (0x00000002): audio            - Render the audio stream
                           (0x00000004): text             - Render subtitles
                           (0x00000008): vis              - Render visualisation when no video is present
                           (0x00000010): soft-volume      - Use software volume
                           (0x00000020): native-audio     - Only use native audio formats
                           (0x00000040): native-video     - Only use native video formats
                           (0x00000080): download         - Attempt progressive download buffering
                           (0x00000100): buffering        - Buffer demuxed/parsed data
                           (0x00000200): deinterlace      - Deinterlace video if necessary
                           (0x00000400): soft-colorbalance - Use software color balance
```

If you want to extract audio and transcode it, you probably need to write some code.

Comment: I already have a working pipeline with decodebin and appsink, which gives me access to raw transcoded pcm16 16khz audio, thanks!
Seem's like I've found the problem. 

Decodebin2 (which by the way is used in playbin) decodes all the streams which it can find in source file/stream/etc. Seems like decodebin3 which is in development right now is going to get rid of that useless CPU usage.